# How to expect a Mock method to be called "Any" number of times in Groovy

Tags: groovy, easymock

I can't find a formal way in Groovy's MockFor object to define an expected call that can be called any number of times as in EasyMock, using `anyTimes()`

I know I could define a range of '1..999' and I would be covering what I want, but I wonder if there is such a "anyTimes()" method available, as I couldn't find any reference to it with Google.

Thanks

Comment: what object are you trying to mock? there might be an alternate way to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

No, to my knowledge, you can not specify and infinite range.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both. It seems there is no such a functionality in Groovy Mocks. Anyway, using a wide enough range for expected calls works out.